# How do I format python regex to add a space after the first 2 characters, then the next groups of 3 characters?

Tags: python, regex

I would like to format a string of a number such as 11084556888 into 11 084 556 888 using regex and `re.sub`. So far I have `(.{3})(?!$)` using replacement `"\\1 "` which results in 110 845 568 88.

Tried:
"pat": `"(.{3})(?!$)"`,
"repl": `"\\1 "`

Results: 110 845 568 88

Expected results: 11 084 556 888

Comment: Might suffice to [replace `\B(?=(?:\d{3})+\b)` with space](https://regex101.com/r/gL9ynY/1).

Comment: ...or replace [(?<=\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+\b)](https://regex101.com/r/SrfULo/1) with a space.

Comment: @bobble, that's OK if the digits comprise a string but if the string were `a123` it would return `"a,123"` (which of course you know).

Comment: what if there is one less digit? should the priority be to have a leading group of 2 (and in consequence the last group has length 2) or that all trailing groups  have 3 digits (but the first  just 1)?

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing the string:

```py
import re

s = "11084556888"

s = re.sub(r".{3}", r"\g<0> ", s[::-1])[::-1]
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
11 084 556 888
```